# Selenium webdriver Java login

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, xpath

I am new to **selenium webdriver** and I want to automate a webpage related to my project. I am currently working on login page, however I facing problem with the login button which I am confused which locator to use. The login button is below:

```
a href="javascript:LoginSubmit('Log In')">
img border="0" src="/opensso/login_images/button_enter.gif" 
alt="enter / entrez"
```

Can you guys please help me out how to use the above with **xPath** or anything related to **JavaScript**?

Sorry if I am missing anything, as I am very new to this.

Comment: you need to provide the whole HTML page in order to extract the xpath expression.

Comment: this edit is wrong, you should not have commented out "img" and "src" attributes @ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: @YuZhang: both is already commented, i just highlight code lines. nothing is edit by me.

Comment: ok, thank you for clearing it up. my apology @ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: While checking with **selenium IDE** , the command is **ClickandWait** and the **xPath:img** is : **//img[@alt='enter / entrez']**

Comment: @RachanaBanik, but what if there are other elements which share the same attributes and placed ahead of this one? Your xpath would located the wrong element.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to click on Anchor(a) tag rather than the image. (Without looking on the actual page not sure if that's the case.)

Try with

`//a/img[@alt='enter / entrez']/..` or 
`//a/img[contains(@src,'button_enter.gif']/..`

The "/.." takes you back to the anchor tag, it similar to navigating to parent directory from the command line.

Comment: Hi , I need to click on to the particular button(it's a login button ) . How can I do using java ?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/img[@alt='enter / entrez']/..")).click();

Comment: glad to help, please accept the answer if it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'javascript:LoginSubmit') and contains(@src, '/opensso/login_images/button_enter.gif')]")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@alt, 'enter / entrez')]")).click();
```